# SQL 1 foreign table 2 primary tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables holding two different types of data. I want to join them to one foreign table but there seems to be a foreign key restraint. Is it possible to work with the following data structure or should I consider an alternative?

Table 1

```
PanID (int PK) - Circuit (nvarchar PK) - Phase  (nvarchar)
1          -         14           -          A
2          -         17           -          B
3          -         19           -          C
```

---

Table 2

```
PanID (int PK) - Circuit (nvarchar PK) - Base  (int)
4          -         C1           -         250
5          -         C2           -         400
6          -         C5           -         250
```

---

Table 3

```
PanID (int PK) - Circuit (nvarchar PK) - POC  (int)
1         -          14          -          1
2         -          17          -          2
3         -          19          -          3
4         -          C1          -          4
5         -          C2          -          5
6         -          C5          -          6
```

---

Table 3 has values on PanID and Circuit unique to both Table 1 and Table 2.

Can I construct an SQL relationship based on this structure?

Comment: I think UNION will work here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's ok for a query but I am trying to set up constraints

Comment: The usual question would usually be - why are table 1 and table 2 separate tables given they apparently deal with the same "type" of things, such that a single reference to them from table 3 makes sense? I.e. you probably wouldn't have separate `MaleEmployees` and `FemaleEmployees` tables - so are you actually performing attribute splitting here? Or should there be a common base table that both table 1 and table 2 should refer to, containing the common columns?

Comment: There are two different types of panel, they have different associated objects. As you can see from the sample, column 3 in table 1 is a nvarchar where as in table 2 its an int. That was the reason for the split.

Comment: Introduce another table, with only PanID and Circuit columns, add a surrogate PK if you like, and make a reference from all three table to this one.